# Meaning of “cross-reference against”

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

What does it mean if one thing is "cross referenced against" the other?
Like the following example:

> Each story is cross-referenced ***against*** the other.

Comment: I don't see why it is off-topic, but the answer is obtainable from commonly available sources.

Answer (score 1):

"Cross-referenced against" basically means a kind of linkage from one part of the document to the other part of the document.
Just like you may find a 'See Also' link in between of a document linking to some document.
OR
You can find links like 'For Details Read Para/Chapter/..' in a document/book referencing to some other section of the same document/book.

> Each story is cross-referenced against the other.

This might mean that either of the story has been linked to the other story, unsure if the links have been physically defined or it is logically cross-referenced.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but if the two stories are linked together then we should probably say "is cross-referenced to each other" not "against, isn't? Could the use of "against" here mean exactly the opposite of "linked together"?

Comment: @Misha99 Against is being used here as in def. 3 at Webster's: "compared or contrasted with" http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/against  *Cross-checked for consistency* might be another way of saying it.